# Modal not working properly

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am facing a problem with the pop up modal in Angularjs. I have a button and on clicking I need to show a modal. Here is my code. When I click on Details button for first time, the modal pop up appears but when I click again.. the app.directive doesn't get called. Greatly appreciate the help. Thanks.

JS:

```
myApp.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.title = attrs.title;
                scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
                  if(value == true)
                    $(element).modal('show');
                  else
                    $(element).modal('hide');
                });

                $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
                  scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
                  });
                });

                $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
                  scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
                  });
                });
            }
    };
});

.state("abc"){
  controller:function(){
     $scope.showModal = false;
     $scope.toggleModal = function(){
        $scope.showModal = false;
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
        var aclpGuid = $stateParams.aclpGuid;
     };
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<td>
    <button ng-click="toggleModal()">Details</button>
    <modal visible="showModal">                       
        <label>Room Details</label>                        
    </modal>
</td>
```

Comment: I guess you should pass `$scope.showModal` to false when you close your modal

Comment: even though I pass the value false, the app.directive doesn't get called 2nd time.

Comment: Have you seen u-bootstrap?  It has a pure angular implementation of the bootstrap modal.

Comment: No.. I used the code through another jsFiddle example.. Its working there.. There is something wrong I am doing here.

Comment: Do u see any console errors the second time you click on the button?

Comment: no console errors.

Comment: Suggestion! Please try to use ui-bootstrap for model popup. Because it provides angularized controls with add-on features, so you don't have to code too much. It also provides other controls also. Model-popup example using ui-bootstrap https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/74exww04/. For UI-bootstrap website https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the issue is the **isolate scope** which you have here `scope:true` inside the directive. Using this, the scope inside a directive is seperated from the scope outside. To confirm this I checked the scope variable with and without `scope: true`. Note the `$$watchers` here:

Without `scope: true`

[image: $$watchers]

With `scope: true`

[image: $$watchers1]

The isolated scope has `$$watchers == null`. So any changes in the scope variable `showDialog` doesn't fire the watch event. So you might wanna use the parent scope i.e the controller's scope here.

The event fires once as when compiling the directive for the first time it attaches the `$watchers` to the element only once and for subsequent calls there is no relation between the outer scope to a directive's inner scope.

With that change and few others I have a working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/iRst0WBTqDK7x1LiZyel).

*controller:*

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showDialog = false;
    $scope.toggleModal = function() {
        $scope.showDialog = !$scope.showDialog;
    };
});
```

Setting the `showDialog` to `false`, whenever the user closes the modal as @Mistalis suggested.

```
$(element).bind('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
        scope.showDialog = false;
    });
});
```

*directive:*

```
myApp.directive('modal', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'modal-partial.html',
        //scope: true,
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.showModal = function(visible, elem) {
                if (!elem)
                    elem = element;

                if (visible)
                    $(elem).modal("show");
                else
                    $(elem).modal("hide");
            }
            scope.title = attrs.title;

            scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value) {
                if (value === true)
                    $(element).modal('show');
                else
                    $(element).modal('hide');
            });

            $(element).bind('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
                });
            });

            $(element).bind('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
                    scope.showDialog = false;
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```